# Embed a server within Android or iOS app that uses Python

Tags: android, python, ios, http, server

I have a python library that I want to use for the core logic of an Android and iOS app. One solution would be to put the python logic into a server and interact with my app through HTTP. If the server is remote though, the user will have to remain online to use the app. Is there anyway I can embed a HTTP server within the apps so that the user doesn't have to be online?

Comment: for IOS you can use PyobjC and for android you can just Cythonize your code and import it as JAVA module or you can also you android NDK, Cythonizing(cython.org) your code will convert your python code in C

Comment: how would you import the c code as a Java module without NDK?

Comment: Is your library pure Python of does it use C(++) modules?

Comment: Its pure Python but it looks like I can convert that to C with Cython